# How to run jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin on multiple result files

Tags: maven-2, jmeter

I'm using the plugin jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin in maven to perform some performance test analysis (generate detailed reports with charts), i have configured the plugin to take as input all jtl files, but after running i remarked that it processed just one file (the first one according alphabetical order), here after my plugin configuration in pom file :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>thread</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>analyze</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${project.build.directory}/**/*.jtl</source>
                        <targetDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/test_report</targetDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Your ideas are welcome...thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i have found how to do it, indeed it was enough to add the property "processAllFilesFound" to the plugin configuration :

```
<configuration>
  <source>${project.build.directory}/**/*.jtl</source>
  <targetDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/test_report</targetDirectory>
  <processAllFilesFound>true</processAllFilesFound>
</configuration>
```