# Jmeter test running using maven

Tags: java, maven, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am learning jmeter and trying to configure it with Maven but I am getting the following exception when I run "mvn verify -e"

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-     plugin:1.9.0:jmeter (jmeter-tests) on project jmeter: C:\qa\jmeter\target\jmeter\results\20150921-JmeterTests.jtl    (The system cannot find the file specified) -> [Help 1]
   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:1.9.0:jmeter (jmeter-tests) on project jmeter: C:\hass-git\cpp_ocp2\cpp_ocp2\qa\jmeter\target\jmeter\results\20150921-JmeterTests.jtl (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
   Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: C:\qa\jmeter\target\jmeter\results\20150921-JmeterTests.jtl (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at com.lazerycode.jmeter.JMeterMojo.parseTestResults(JMeterMojo.java:75)
    at com.lazerycode.jmeter.JMeterMojo.execute(JMeterMojo.java:54)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
```

my pom.xml has

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jmeter</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>analyze</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>

                        <source>${project.build.directory}/**/*.jtl</source>


                        <targetDirectory>${project.build.directory}/results</targetDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My folder structure is

```
  qa/jmeter/src/test/jmeter/jmeterTests.jmx
```

Comment: is this path C:\hass-git\cpp_ocp2\cpp_ocp2\qa\jmeter\target\jmeter\results exists ?  May be, you only need only one cpp_ocp2 ? and did you see that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31879949/how-to-run-jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin-on-multiple-result-files ?

Comment: Yes vincent, this path exist there are two folder of cpp_ocp2. I have changed the configuration to the link you sent to me but still getting the same error

Comment: In which directory is your `pom.xml` located? Normally I would expect it in the `qa/jmeter` directory.

Comment: __TIP__ Comment out the `jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin` to see if it runs without generating the reports. If so, check if the specifiek directory contains the expected file(s). (`<source>${project.build.directory}/**/*.jtl</source>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute `mvn -e -X verify`, to see more output, what goes well and where, when and why the error occurs.

Adds these options to your `jmeter-maven-plugin` and run the jmeter script again. Hopefully some more details are shown, about what exactly is going wrong when. Currently look like the output file is not written or so...

```
<configuration>
    <!-- By default the test results are saved in a file /target/jmeter/results/<testname>-<timestamp>.jtl 
        Further processing is easier without timestamp though. -->
    <testResultsTimestamp>false</testResultsTimestamp>

    <!-- To simplify debugging, it is advisable to adapt the loglevel. The 
        jmeter logs are written to the file jmeter.log. -->
    <overrideRootLogLevel>DEBUG</overrideRootLogLevel>

    <!-- By default, the console output during a jmeter test run is suppressed. 
        We want to display the progress using the listener "Generate Summary Results" 
        (which periodically prints stats to stdout). Therefore we have to make sure, 
        that the jmeter output is not suppressed. -->
    <suppressJMeterOutput>false</suppressJMeterOutput>

    <!-- If tests fail (e.g. a http-request running into a timeout), the corresponding 
        maven goal also fails (and subsequent goals aren't executed anymore). We 
        want to create graphs from test-results, no matter if some requests failed 
        or not, so we ignore jmeter failures. -->
    <ignoreResultFailures>true</ignoreResultFailures>
</configuration>
```

**TIP:** Use latest [jmeter-maven-plugin](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lazerycode.jmeter/jmeter-maven-plugin) (currently version 1.10.1)